# Touches Ended not called when subclassed with UIGestureRecogniser

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am trying to create a custom gesture recogniser for my view. I am following this answer mentioned in here: But for some reason the touched Ended and also touches movied are not getting called. Only touches began get called.

*SubClass*:

```
#import "TapGesture.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation TapGesture

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}

@end
```

and I am initialising the TapGesture as follows:

```
TapGesture *tapGesture=[[TapGesture alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(incrementValue)];
tapGesture.delaysTouchesEnded=NO;
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
[_workButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture]; //_workButton is a UIView
```

I don;t have any other gesture recognisers in the view. If I use the same methods in the UIView, all of them are called as expected.

Why the touchesEnded/touchesMoved are not getting called when overrride in UIGestureRecogniser class ?

Answer (score 4):

When subclassing `UIGestureRecognizer` you must make it act like a *continuous* gesture and handle it's state machine by yourself (i.e., manually set it's `state`).

From the iOS Developer Library Docs on *UIGestureRecognizer*:

> Subclasses must set the state property to the appropriate value when they transition between states.

[See here for more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/) (Scroll down to **Subclasing Notes**)

- Note: to make `state` read/write and not read-only, you should use `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h` as also noted on the docs:

  > The state property is declared in UIGestureRecognizer.h as being read-only. This property declaration is intended for clients of gesture recognizers. Subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer must import UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h. This header file contains a redeclaration of state that makes it read-write.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is required for a double tap gesture but not for a single tap gesture:

```
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
```